# Is there a reason why you can like your own post?

Tags: social-interfaces, microinteractions

Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter all enable you to like/favorite your own post. Is there a reason behind why they allow you to favorite your own post? Should it be done an alternate way?

There doesn't seem to be any real negative since you don't gain anything from the like directly. At the same time, the purpose of a like is to either help filter content for your preferences, share stuff you like with the people who follow you, and to show support to the poster. None of these apply when you like your own post. Why is this a feature?

Comment: "There doesn't seem to be any real negative" = that's your answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### I worked on a social network recently and debated exactly this issue.

We came to the same conclusion. Here's why:

- It provides **consistency of experience**. Users expect to be able to comment, like, or share posts.  So removing one of these actions for your own post can create frustration because of the lack of consistency.
- **Don't penalize users for posting or expressing themselves**.  Most social networks want to encourage, not discourage posting.  So users who are excited about posting something may want to express that excitement further by liking their own post.  Saying "no" to that creates unnecessary friction for users.
- **It doesn't hurt the platform**.  You may decide to count the like for the purposes of scoring the content.  But if you don't want to, you can totally ignore self-likes for scoring.  The user doesn't have to know, and probably won't care even if they did know.
- **It's not worth saying 'no' to users**.  If you don't provide a like button, users may feel like their post has been amputated.  Then you are going to have to explain in a help section why you don't let users like their own posts. If you do provide a like button, you will have to tell the user that she can't like her own post.  Given the low impact of allowing likes, it'st just not worth the cost of telling the user no.

Comment: Unless you're on ux.stackexchange.com where you couldn't vote for your own answer ;)

Comment: Agreed... UX.SE has some terrible UX flaws. Foremost for me is this, which results in poorly asked questions that waste the community's time:  http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/make-the-ux-se-question-interface-suck-less

Comment: Indeed I'm not aware of any stackexchange feature that would allow any sub-site like UX.SE to customize the ask-a-question flow...

Answer (score 2):

Yes think about facebooks algorithms in regards to the massive amounts of data they have and how they can only show you a limited subset of this data.

What you like helps change what you will actually see or the preferred items they show you. Thus a user can like certain things they post about maybe a small market hockey team like the Winnipeg Jets or the New Jersey Devils that way they can see more posts related to that area.

That was just my speculation but it seems as though [Other sources confirm it and encourage you to always like your own posts](http://blog.cityblast.com/why-you-should-always-like-your-own-facebook-status/). [This one also agrees](http://www.ricksdailytips.com/why-you-should-always-like-your-own-facebook-posts/). Below are some excerpts:

> - It Can Help More Of Your Friends See Your Post, As Well As Their Network. Ever notice you often see things on your news feed that the
>     people you interact with the most liked?
> - Also users see things that you recently liked or were a fan of on different ticker style feeds so liking key posts that you want to
>     share will encourage others to see it. It's sort of a way to broadcast
>     things with a little extra emphasis.

Let it be known though that not [everyone is a fan of self liking.](http://disputations.gawker.com/stop-liking-your-instagram-photos-1609717874) However, I do not see a threat of damaging online social communities by enabling the concept of self liking your own posts.

Answer (score 0):

Personal experience: I sometimes favorite my own tweets because that kicks off a IFTTT job that will archive that tweet to Evernote. So, it's part of a loose and inelegant workflow. Sometimes a "Like" isn't because you like something.

Answer (score 0):

A person can only give themselves one like. So if someone else only wants to look at things with a lot of likes, that one vote won't make a difference.